# Why is this recursion python code print y and cant return y?

Tags: python, recursion

So I have tried to create a recursion function which returns factorial of a number. I cant make it return y but I dont know why, can someone explain?

```
y = 1
def factorial(x):
    global y
    if x <= 1:
        print(y)
        return y
    else:
        y = y * x
        factorial(x-1)

def hey(): #random funtion which can return y but factorial cant.
    return y

print(factorial(3))
print(hey())
```

result in terminal:

```
6 #factorial can print y
None# Cant return y
6 # Other function can return y
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to propagate the return:

```py
def factorial(x):
    global y
    if x <= 1:
        print(y)
        return y
    else:
        y = y * x
        return factorial(x-1)
```

Also, there's no need to use a global variable, a simpler solution:

```py
def factorial_recursive(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * factorial_recursive(x-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the `return` before the recursion, and also why are you using a `global` variable ??, here's a simpler version without your `y`:

```
def factorial(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * factorial(x-1)

print(factorial(3))
```

output:

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I forgot to propagate the return.
I was accually using a global variable just to make things more interesting, testing, and it worked.
Now I understand the code.